# Как правильно создавать таблицы в базе данных SQLite под Аndroid?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Всем привет.

Изучаю помаленьку программирование под андроид. Есть один вопрос. Как создавать базу данных, уже понял, создавать таблицу - в принципе, тоже. Вот скрипт:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_QUERY = 
            "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
                            UID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
                            NAME + "varchar(255))";
```

Но только чтобы его написать без ошибок, я чуть не угробил ноут. Слишком много всяких кавычек, плюсиков.

Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ создания таблиц, может быть, автоматизированный сервис, или так и придется мучиться с таким синтаксисом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать какую-нибудь ORM (например, [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)) — они, как правило, все заботы о создании таблиц берут на себя. Или же просто написать свой `statement builder`, на что уйдёт менее получаса.

Не стоит также забывать и о том, что SQLite — typeless database, поэтому типы данных столбцов можно не указывать (за исключением autoincrement pk столбца).